# Firebase realtime database backend async function not updating users

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I call this function when I have a list of users who i want to update. The console.logs and resolve message are in perfect order and what I expect. But nothing gets written/changed on the realtime database. It looks completely untouched. Did I do the promise wrong? Any guidance appreciated, thank you.

```
function updateUsers(){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        objectLength = Object.keys(usersUpdate).length;
        for (let i=0; i < objectLength; i++){
            admin.database().ref('users/' + usersUpdate[i].key + '/notifications/' + usersUpdate[i].notif).update({
                "sendPush" : 0,
            })
            .then(()=>{
                console.log('updated user ' + i);
                if (i == (objectLength-1)){
                    resolve('resolved updateUsers');
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => console.log('Error ' + error));
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently firebase doesn't like being passed integers. Lesson learned. Turned the value to "0" instead of 0 and it worked.